# Alter Attribute of restriction of the Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, restriction

I need to alter Attribute of restriction of the Foreign Key with script. Is it Possible without dropping the key and recreating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK dropping the constraint and then recreating it with your new attribute is the only way.